# Is it possible for Bangladesh to fully adopt British laws?

Tags: united-kingdom, comparative-law

How different is British law and Bangladeshi law?

What practical problems may arise if Bangladesh adopts British civil and criminal laws in entirety?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the background to this question? Is this a likely scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are many areas where British law is similar to Bangladeshi law because Bangladeshi law was derived originally from the law of Pakistan which was derived from the law of India which was devised by British lawyers at its inception in the colonial period, there has been seventy years for Bangladeshi law to drift from British colonial law, which wasn't identical to British law even then.

There are lots of differences. Some of the most notable include:

- Family law is completely different due to local religious considerations, and this is not easily changed because people have built families in reliance upon them.
- Criminal laws have offenses arising from the concerns of South Asia and Islam that differ from British law.
- Even though lawyers mostly deal with what is called "private law", something like 90% of statutes involve what is called "public law", i.e. the organization of government and matters like tax law that are very particular to the bureaucracy and local government structure that has arisen over time in Bangladesh.
- Property laws need to respect vested property interests and those differ significantly in Bangladesh and Britain.

It would certainly be possible to copy many British laws on many subject, but a wholesale adoption of British law in its entirety would be an incoherent disaster.

Comment: "Bangladesh deals with multiple languages" ???

Comment: @anonymous I stand corrected and have removed that from my post. I read a lot about minority linguistic populations in Bangladesh in anthropology discussions, but apparently the single national language enshrined in the Constitution is spoken by 98% of the population (unlike India which has linguistic diversity), although until 1987 its laws were primarily written in English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangladesh#Languages